# Regulations for traveling with LiPo battery in homemade electronic

Tags: canada, airport-security, regulations, batteries

In a month I will be flying to Costa Rica from Canada. I am working on a solar panel phone charger that will have a built in battery storage. The battery that will be used is a 2000mAh single cell LiPo battery. Is there's an regulations that will prevent me from bringing this battery on the plane?

Also, is there any restriction or suggestions on bring an homemade electronic to lower the chances of it getting flagged at airport security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your query, the possible scenarios are,

1. Carrying a LiPo battery in allowed only on carry-on luggage. Also, as you are working on some solar project, you need to provide the reason to have this battery.
2. You should declare this in advance at each security stop. TSA guys will be more friendly if you could give them a valid reason to have this battery.
3. I don't think they allow you to carry any experimental setup in carry-on luggage so you may need to detach your battery from rest of the setup and then carry it.
4. Contact your Air Line in advance and clear this with them if they allow you carry it on board. Check if there are certain formalities.

PS: Do not hide any details or purpose of having a battery with you. Being an experimental setup, I guess the battery will look bit different than the regular one.

Hope this helps!

-AG

Comment: Yes, put the device without te battery in checked luggage, but keep the battery in you carry on. Make sure any connectors are well isolated (cover them with tape) and protect the battery from shocks and puncture (use some bubble wrap). Shouldn’t be an issue to carry them, I have carried half a dozen of 9000 mAh batteries several times, most of the time they didn’t even blink.

Comment: @jcaron what do you put your batteries in while taking them on a plane? Do you put them in a LiPo charging bag while taking them on a plane?

Comment: I just put tape on the connectors and wrap them up (individually) in bubble wrap. This goes beyond the [IATA recommendation](https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Documents/passenger-lithium-battery.pdf) which states "The terminals of all spare batteries must be protected from short circuit by enclosing them in their original retail packaging or taping over the terminals or separate plastic bags for each battery". This applies for "small" Lithium-Ion batteries below 100 Wh carried as spares in unlimited quantity in carry-on luggage.

Comment: Note that the IATA recommendation is not necessarily the final word. Even though most airlines will follow those rules, they are free to have more strict rules if they want to, so check with them (in many cases you'll find the relevant info on their website).